# Type checking for generic methods in Dart seems to be broken

Tags: generics, dart

Type checking for generic methods in Dart seems to be broken.

In testGoodCall() where the class has a generic type it works as expected, the compiler flags an error on the String being passed where a bool should be expected.

But as can be seen in the example code below , **the compiler is oblivious to the incorrect type of the second parameter being passed in testBadCall()**.

**Is this a known issue?**

**What is the work around?** - without creating a class for every method that I want generic's with proper type checking on.

```
void testGoodCall() {
  var b = I<bool>();
  b.testGood(b, "");   // compiler flags an error on this line as expected
}

void testBadCall() {
  var b = I<bool>();
  b.testBad(b, "");   // compiler ignores the error this line should cause
}

class I<T> {
  void testGood(I<T> value1, T value) {}

  void testBad<A>(I<A> value1, A value) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it works as expected. In you testBad example you expect Dart to automatically find a type for `A` which makes `b.testBad(b, "")` valid. Well, it is completely valid if `A` is set to the type `Object`. You can see that if you print the type:

```
  void testBad<A>(I<A> value1, A value) {
    print(A); // Object
  }
```

If you instead create the object where you specify the type for `A` like:

```
void testBadCall() {
  var b = I<bool>();
  b.testBad<String>(b, ""); // compiler returns: The argument type 'I<bool>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'I<String>'
}
```

You get the error you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, since you don't explicitly tell Dart what `A` is, the compiler tries to infer it, and it infers it to be type `Object` just like it would do for the list `[true, 1, 'string']`. I understand how that can be surprising, but that's how it is. If you want better type checking, you have to tell Dart explicitly what `A`is: `b.testBad<bool>(b, "");` Now it produces an error.